# $all not working with array

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongodb-ruby

I am trying to get all `submissions` documents that contain all of the `tags` listed in an array.

My current code looks like this:

```
submissions.find({ tags: { $all => tags } })
print tags.count
```

However, upon running, I receive the following error on the second line:

```
BSON::InvalidKey at /
NilClass instances are not allowed as keys in a BSON document.
```

It should also be noted that the following *does* work as it should (though it does not achieve my desired result):

```
submissions.find({ tags: tags })
print tags.count
```

How can I fix my original code to find the wanted documents properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $all expression in MongoDB is:

```
submissions.find({ tags: { $all: tags }});
```

In this case, "tags" must be an array (`tags = ['tag1','tag2','tag3']`)

Why do you used "$all => tags" instead "$all: tags" ?

Comment: I was trying that at first, but it was giving me a syntax error, so I changed it. After you pointed this out, I realized that the '$all' was supposed to be a string in ruby, which was the source of the error. Thanks!